# jackson UnrecognizedPropertyException during readvalue

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to convert JsonString to Java object.

Json object

```
[{
"id": "2",
"tipo": "0",
"data": "prova"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "tipo": "0",
    "data": "prova2"
}]
```

object

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Variazione {
    @JsonProperty("id") int id;
    @JsonProperty("tipo") int tipo;
    @JsonProperty("data") String data;

    @JsonCreator
    public Variazione() {

    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTipo(int tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Variazione[] obj = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://www.url"),
                Variazione[].class);
```

When I try to convert JSON to Java class using the mapper, it's throwing an UnrecognizedPropertyException.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "id" (class testvari.Test), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
>    at [Source: url; line: 2, column: 9] (through reference chain: Object[][0]->testvari.Test["id"])
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:855)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1083)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1389)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1367)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:266)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:163)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:135)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1119)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:298)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:196)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:20)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3788)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
>       at testvari.Test.main(Test.java:49)

the other question on stackoverflow with a similar problem all came from different version of the jar file (annotation/core) but i'm using only 2.x

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
```

any idea how to fix this problem?
i tried to add the @jsonproperty but the problem is still here

full code here

```
package testvari;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;

public class Test extends java.util.TimerTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test = new Test();
        try {


            String json = "[{\r\n" + 
    "   \"id\": \"2\",\r\n" + 
    "   \"tipo\": \"0\",\r\n" + 
    "   \"data\": \"prova\"\r\n" + 
    "}, {\r\n" + 
    "   \"id\": \"3\",\r\n" + 
    "   \"tipo\": \"0\",\r\n" + 
    "   \"data\": \"prova2\"\r\n" + 
    "}]";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Variazione[] obj = mapper.readValue(json,
                Variazione[].class);
            System.out.println(obj[0].id);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
    public class Variazione {
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
        @JsonProperty("id") int id;
        @JsonProperty("tipo") int tipo;
        @JsonProperty("data") String data;

        @JsonCreator
        public Variazione() {

        }

        @JsonProperty("id")
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @JsonProperty("tipo")
        public void setTipo(int tipo) {
            this.tipo = tipo;
        }

        @JsonProperty("data")
        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }


    }

}
```

not much different from the split version :-)

Comment: That doesn't seem like what you're really deserializing. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i posted the code... but was almost the same.. the JSON is an array of objects {int,int,string} ... the class _Variazione_ is an object with int,int,string

Comment: yes and the code came from a php encode ... so i don't think is the problem... btw i tried to change _id_ and _tipo_ in String and nothing changed

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis why duplicate of something where the problem is a nested class? the error is the same but the solution isn't close

Comment: Your code works for me if I make the inner class static as the duplicate suggests. Jackson has no way to create an instance of the enclosing class for the properties you've provided.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis oh right tnx was searching this problem from this morning... lost a day for a **static** i'm sad :-(